# Creating dynamic list using data returned from database after a button is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have simple buttons in my web page. What i want is when anybody clicks a button, the paragraph below it gets populated with the results from a database query (that returns two columns). The list text includes elements of the first column. The list items act as hyperlinks with the source document being pointed to by elements of the second column.

For eg :
if the database table is

Name           Link

---

Video1          url1
Video2          url2
Video3          url3

i want there to be the equivalent html code to be dynamically generated (after a button is pressed)

```
<ul>
<li><a href="url1">Video1</a>
<li><a href="url2">Video2</a>
<li><a href="url3">Video3</a>
<ul>
```

ive been reading around and i guess AJAX is the man for the job. but i ust cant seem to figure it out

Comment: AJAX request + some javascript is indeed a good idea. What can't you exactly figure out? What have you tried?

Comment: You could do it without AJAX but the page would have to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice example of how to use ajax to grab data:

[Performing GET and POST requests using Ajax](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost.shtml)

The PHP side is pretty basic. Just list the content you need from the database.
Also make sure you are protected against SQL injections.